# Maximize Volume of Triangular Prism given Surface Area

Tags: calculus, optimization, volume

A open topped box is to be constructed with an equilateral triangular base of side a. The sides of the box are to be rectangles (a by h). Find the dimensions of a box which has the maximum volume and surface area of 300 square centimeters.

I know that the area of the triangle is the square root of 3 divided by 4 multiplied by a square.

Comment: Are both (a and h) are variable as long as surface area remains constant (unvaried)?

Comment: yes. that is correct

Comment: How many "sides" do you consider ? 4, 5, 6 ? Above 4, it will be difficult for all of them to be $a \times h$, unless $a=h$ ?

Comment: The surface area can be maximum of 300 sq cm. It is a triangular prism so there's only 3 sides.

Comment: If the sides are triangular, and you say at the same time that they are rectangular $a \times h$, I don't understand. Couldn't you provide a sketch of the volume ?

Comment: The sides are rectangular and the base is triangular. I am describing an open topped triangular prism with sides consisting of rectangles

Comment: Thanks ! It's very clear now with the word "prism". I should have guessed : your text is clear enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assumed that h is the height of the sides. Then we would have the volume given by the following expression:
$$V = \frac{a^2\sqrt3}{4}*h$$
Also, the box is opened on top, so the area is given by:
$$A =\frac{a^2\sqrt3}{4}+3ah=300$$
Isolating h, we have:
$$h = \frac{300 - \frac{a^2\sqrt3}{4}}{3a} $$
Substituting h in the volume expression, we get:
$$V = \frac{a^2\sqrt3}{4}*\frac{300 - \frac{a^2\sqrt3}{4}}{3a}$$
Deriving V in respect to a, and then equalizing to 0, in order to find a local maximum, we have:
$$a = \frac{20}{\sqrt[4]{3}}$$
Applying that value of a to V:
$$V_{max} = \frac{1000}{(\sqrt[4]{3})^3}$$

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer! I do have one question, when you solved for h, what happened to the 4 in the denominator?

Comment: You mean the 4 from the area of the triangle? It continues there in the expression of h.

Comment: Oh I see. Thank you

Comment: One final question, how would I find the actual dimensions of the prism, like the sides of the triangle and the length of the sides?

Comment: Well, the dimensions you need are **a** and **h**. You have **a**, and to find **h**, all you have to do is substitute a with its value on the expression for **h**, which is the third expression of my answer.

Comment: Nice answer! Plus 1.